# Program closes in Dev-C++

Tags: c, syntax

This is the code I have entered. I am a beginner at programming and can't understand why the computer ignores the command to return an A or B

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int main (void){
        float grade;

        printf ("Enter grade");
        scanf  ("%d",&grade);

        if (grade >= 90) {
            printf ("A\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ("B\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: FYI: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works!

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your format specifier in your `scanf` statement. From this:

```
scanf("%d",&grade);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%f",&grade);
```

Because `%d` is for `integer's` and `%f` is for `float`.

For more infromation about `scanf()` see this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score -1):

The `scanf` format string should be `"%f"` (`float`) instead of `"%d"` (`int`). C++ will blindly store an `int` in the memory allocated for the `float`. The other code will then try to interpret those bits as a float, which will get strange results.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with my C/C++, but I'm *pretty* sure having the wrong format specifier nets you undefined behavior (so although you could end up with what you describe, that isn't guaranteed to happen)

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks alot for your help and clear explanation.